# Zabbix Trigger for text change

Tags: zabbix

I am trying to create a trigger for changes in JSON file that I get from endpoint.
I've already created item that excludes web page header and only leaves json file contents as plain text.

```
{"state": true 
"riskName":"example"
"errorMessage":null}
{"state": false
"riskName":"example"
"errorMessage":"errorMessage-example"}
```

I was wondering if it's possible in zabbix to trigger event based on state change true -> false and show the errorMessage that's connected to {"state":false} event
Please correct me if I'm going in wrong direction

Answer (score 0):

Create dependent item, use Preprocessing JSONPath $.state - so you will have only short value "true" or "false".
Then create trigger with condition last(item)="true".